# Refresh screen every 5 mins

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, vbscript, windows-server-2008

I have got windows server which I used to connect via remote desktop, but gets locked if I leave it idle, and there is no way I could change the timeout of remote desktop options, so I want to write a **batch file** or **vbscript** or **powershell** which would run in the windows server and refreshes itself(F5) or a mouse click or mouse movement like every 5 mins.

```
server 2008 R2 entreprise 64-bit
```

Comment: You could look at using VBscript and use the SENDKEYS method.  I am sure powershell has a similar capability but batch-files do not.

Comment: I've used this tool for similar environments.  https://mousejiggler.codeplex.com/  It's a TINY binary which jiggles a virtual mouse every so often.

Comment: You should do it with vbscript

Comment: My answer is ready for you, so, if you want it in vbscript, just, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41860921/edit) your question and add the tag **vbscript**

Comment: @Hackoo added vbscript

Comment: @FoxDeploy I tried using that software, but it still locked out

Comment: Do you have admin access on the machine?

Comment: @FoxDeploy - yes, I do

Comment: You can remote in, and take ownership of the registry keys for screen timeout and group policy screen time out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try for this vbscript :

```
Option Explicit
If AppPrevInstance() Then 
    MsgBox "There is an existing proceeding !" & VbCrLF &_
    CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation,"There is an existing proceeding !"    
    WScript.Quit  
Else   
    Dim Ws
    set Ws = createobject("Wscript.Shell")
    Do
        Ws.Sendkeys "{F5}"
        Pause 5 '==> To sleep for 5 minutes
    Loop
End If   
'**************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
        " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function   
'**************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'**************************************************************************
Sub Pause(min)
    Wscript.Sleep(min*1000*60)
End sub
'**************************************************************************
```